# Для чего выполнять функцию в assert?

Tags: flutter, dart

Изучая библиотеку provider наткнулся на вот такой код.
Не могу понять для чего вызывать анонимную функцию, которая просто присваивает новое значение переменной _debugIsSelecting, в assert.

```
 bool _debugIsSelecting = true;

 assert(() {
    _debugIsSelecting = false;
    return true;
  }());
```

Comment: Таким образом код определяет что его отлаживают и имеет возможность поменять своё поведение (что бы облегчить отладку или чтобы затруднить отладку).